# SQL Update Query not updating records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of games that when clicked lead to a form that allows users to edit records before updating them.

Here is the Edit Games page;

```
<?php
$gameID = isset($_GET['gameID']) ? $_GET['gameID'] : '';
$gameYear = isset($_GET['gameYear']) ? $_GET['gameYear'] : '';
$gamePrice = isset($_GET['gamePrice']) ? $_GET['gamePrice'] : '';
$gameName = isset($_GET['gameName']) ? $_GET['gameName'] : '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE gameName = $gameName";
  $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) 
  or die (mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult);        

    $gameID = $row['gameID'];
    $gameYear = $row['gameYear'];
    $gamePrice = $row['gamePrice'];
    $gameName = $row['gameName'];       

 ?>

<div id="form">
<form action="updateGame.php" id="Update" method="get">
<label> Game ID
  <input id="text" name="id" value = "<?php echo $gameID; ?>" />
</label>
<label> Year
  <input type = "text" name = "year" value = "<?php echo $gameYear; ?>" />
</label>
<label> Price
  <input type = "text" name = "price" value = "<?php echo $gamePrice; ?>" />
</label>
<label> Name
  <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $gameName; ?>" />
</label>

<input type = "submit" value = "Update">
```

Here is the update page that runs when the submit button is clicked;

```
<?php
$gameID = isset($_GET['gameID']) ? $_GET['gameID'] : '';
$gameYear = isset($_GET['gameYear']) ? $_GET['gameYear'] : '';
$gamePrice = isset($_GET['gamePrice']) ? $_GET['gamePrice'] : '';
$gameName = isset($_GET['gameName']) ? $_GET['gameName'] : '';

$sql = "UPDATE game SET gameYear = '$gameYear', gamePrice = '$gamePrice', gameName = '$gameName' WHERE gameID = '$gameID'";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql) 
or die (mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);

echo "Updated";

?>
```

The edit games page works and I can edit the records, when I press the submit button it comes up with the echo statement saying the record was updated, however, no changes happen and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should always escape your variables before using them in your query. you can use `$conn->escape_string($string)` in your example, where `$string` has to be replaced with your `$_GET['index']` parameters

Comment: Also, have you checked if the `$_GET` variables are actually set? You should consider `echo`ing there.

Comment: i have a simple way to test if everything is correct, first you echo $sql in your script to get the full query string, copy the query, then you go to phpmyadmin, execute the query, see what error you got

Comment: @RubenRutten thanks for the heads up about the SQL injection. I'll make sure to fix it up before making the site live. However, as I understand, this wouldn't affect why the records don't update currently would it? Thanks for the reply, appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you insert `echo`s everywhere to debug what is actually happening. Echo all variables and your `$sql` variable before query.

Comment: @onegun Thanks, just tried and the query executes without error.

Comment: is the query echoed look correct in the first place? please post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form uses `name="id"`, not `name="gameID"`, so your `$_GET['gameID']` variable is not set on any of your requests, but `$_GET['id']` is. Update your form or your `GET` page, so that the names match.

Comment: i think this could be the answer

Comment: Thanks, that was an error on my part when I formatted the code here. @Ruben Rutten However, whilst just testing the pages I noticed that the records do successfully update (the year, price and name). The gameID doesn't updated (I'd been testing that and assumed none of the records were updating at all). So to be clear, I can edit the records apart from the gameID.

Comment: @RonaIdo, you should never update an ID. An ID should be unique, and if you decide to edit all values, you should keep the ID the same. This way, you'll never get conflicts if you have multiple tables containing referencing to the ID of your game. Is your `gameID` row set to `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`? This makes sure that all inserted values are unique. Regardless, in your query you do not update the ID, a `WHERE` clause will only check, it won't update anything

Comment: @RubenRutten the gameID is just a serial number of the game. If it is entered in incorrectly I'd like the user to be able to edit it. It isn't a primary key. Thanks.

Comment: Then add another column to your table which is an unique identifier for that specific game. Then rewrite your query to also update `gameID = ".$gameID."` and use `WHERE id = ".$id."` as `WHERE` clause

Comment: @RubenRutten Thank you for the help. I'll mark this as the best answer now. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to append the variables in your query. I should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE game SET gameYear = '".$gameYear."', gamePrice = '".$gamePrice."', gameName = '".$gameName."' WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."'";
```

Comment: This is not the problem in his case. Double quoted strings can parse variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: i think his way is also fine, the variable still parsed

Comment: @Rigel1121 Thanks, I've changed the query however the records still do not update.

Comment: @Ronaldo, his way of parsing  variables is just different, his and your method result in the same value of the `$sql` variable. I still strongly recommend to sanitize your query before running it.